# How to import tables with missing values?

Tags: postgresql, bulk-load

I use basketball data tables to get some understanding of Postgres 9.2 & phppgadmin. Therefore I would like to import csv tables into that database. However, I get:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "year"
CONTEXT:  COPY coaches, line 1: ""coachid";"year";"yr_order";"firstname";"lastname";"season_win";"season_loss";"playoff_win";"playoff..."
```

with command:

```
\copy coaches FROM '/Users/Desktop/Database/NBAPostGres/DataOriginal/coaches_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

The current table has no missings. So my questions are:

1. What did I wrong and if using a table with missing values?
2. How to import such table or handle such structure generally(also in respect to missing values)?

Data structure:

```
 coachid    year    yr_order    firstname   lastname    season_win
 HAMBLFR01  204        2          Frank     Hamblen         10
 RUSSEJO01  1946       1          John      Russell         22
```

I used:

```
 varchar     integer   integer  character    character     integer
```

Comment: First: you chose the wrong delimiter (the error message reports there are `';'` in the input, and your command specified `DELIMITER ','` And, since it cannot find a `,` delimiter on the line, the copy command assumes the whole line consists of one field, and chokes when not finding the second (year) column.

Comment: THX. I adjusted it but get ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "year"
CONTEXT:  COPY coaches, line 1, column year: "year". Is it possible that I have to account for the header somehow?(year,coachid are no integer for obvious reasons, so either I change the data type or imply the header in the command. Does it make sense?)

Comment: You *do* have to account for the header - or remove the line from the source.

Comment: yes i got it thx you guys :---).....could someone tell me a bit about how missing values are generally treated in this context. Do I have account somehow for them before import data with missing values?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can have columns missing for the *whole table*. Tell `COPY` (or the psql wrapper `\copy`) to only fill selected columns by appending a column list to the table:

```
\copy coaches (coachid, yr_order, firstname)
FROM '/Users/.../coaches_data.csv' (FORMAT csv, HEADER, DELIMITER ',');
```

Missing values are filled in with column defaults. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html):

> If there are any columns in the table that are not in the column list,
> `COPY FROM` will insert the default values for those columns.

But you **cannot** have values missing for *just some* rows. That's not possible. The text representation of `NULL` can be used (overruling respective column defaults).

It's all in the manual, really:

- [SQL-`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)
- [psql `\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

Comment: I have same problem. I tried this solution, gives me this error: ERROR:  extra data after last expected column

Comment: @RaminZahedi: You must have a destination column for *every* column in the CSV file. And the file must be consistent, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR:  missing data for column "year" CONTEXT:  COPY coaches, line 1:
>   ""coachid";"year";"yr_order";"firstname";"lastname";"season_win";"season_loss";"playoff_win";"playoff..."

This type of error is also the result of a Table-mismatch. The table you are importing the text file into either has more columns or less columns than the text file has.